# Linq extension to recursively retrieve collection of items

Tags: linq

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass();

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public intScore { get; set; }
    public MyClass[] subclasses { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
   .....    
 }
```

The results returned from extrenal source are recursive, I am trying to retrieve the results from the collection using linq or any extension methods using recursion, any help appreciated.

ex; The collection i have is

```
Myclass results=XXXmethod(xxxx)// which gives me results.
```

subclasses is a list of type `Myclass`, so this list will have again some collection, and inturn that can collection agian nested levels

say the service returned 10 results or `Myclass[10]` `Myclass[0]` is having again `Myclass[4]` which might have 2 or 4, need to build a collection allitems

I am trying to do like this but some are missing

```
results.class.subclusters.subclasses (o => o.subclasses )
               .SelectMany(x => x.subclasses ).ToList()
```

but which is not giving correct results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062882/searching-a-tree-using-linq

Answer (score 3):

LINQ itself does not support recursive method, but you can have the recursive method like below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyClass[] SubClasses { get; set; }

    //More properties

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetRecursive()
    {
        yield return this;

        if (SubClasses != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in SubClasses
                          .Where(s => s != null)
                          .SelectMany(x => x.GetRecursive()))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
myClass.GetRecursive()
```

Comment: you might want to add a null filter in there: SubClasses.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(...)

Comment: I am trying to do some thing similar, but not sure how yield works here, Other thing is dont have structure.. i have the results returned as a object of myclass, just wondering how can i call myclass.Getrecursive(), getrecursive should take mylist and return all the children right? Any help appreciated

Comment: @PraveenKonduru: What do you mean "dont have structure" and "the results returned as a object of myclass"?

Comment: I am consuming a service which is returning me these results, and the results are of type. Ofcourse the code what you have sent my results structure is same.Another thing is tried ur code yield return this; here what is this?-- Thanks

Comment: @PraveenKonduru: `yield return this` is the key for you to get the result, you might need to look more you yield: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: appreciate your quick responses basically its  throwing me an excpetion. I was trying in a console appln. thanks.

Comment: @PraveenKonduru: what kind exception you have?

Comment: @Praveen: You are trying to return a ClusterService object in a method that returns Cluster.