# LINQ search records until parentid = 0

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# List with 3 fields: `ID`, `Name` and `ParentID`. I am binding it to a treeview. Now I am also having a search feature where I want to filter the List and rebind the treeview.

If I search for `child-1-1`, my linq should be able to get following records: `parent-1`, `child-1-1`. So that I have to get records containing my search text and than get the record with ID as `ParentID` of this. All `ParentID`s(roots) have `ParentID` value `0` so I have to keep on getting records until `ParentID` is `0`.

Example of Data:

```
ID  Name       ParentID
1   parent-1   0
2   parent-2   0
3   child-1-1  1
4   child-1-2  1
5   child-2-1  2
```

So my question is how can I get a LINQ expression to get records like I described above?

I mean something like `var mydata = from p in this.mylist where...`???

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's your question?

Comment: Please can you provide further elaboration along with the actual form your data structure in your list takes, how you're performing the binding and what you've attempted thus far.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have `List<Node> myList` where `Node` class with properties `(Id, ParentId, ...)` based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7063002/1594178 variant for you

```
static IEnumerable<Node> Parents(this IEnumerable<Node> nodes, int startId)
{
    Node node = nodes.Where(n => n.Id = startId).Single();
    yield return node;
    while (node.ParentId != 0)
    {
        node = nodes.Where(n => n.Id = node.ParentId).Single();
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

to populate `mydata` with parents of your child with id = 3 along with that child use

```
var mydata = mylist.Parents(3)
```