# Flatten IEnumerable with multiple root nodes and select Id property

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following hierarchy and I need to flatten this and select all `Id`s. I have tried using `SelectMany()` like this `.SelectMany(node => node.Children).Select(node => node.Id)`. This will result in a list of **3,5,6**. Is it possible, using Linq to get the complete list **1,2,3,4,5,6,7**?

- Node (Id = 1)
- Node (Id = 2)

  - Node (Id = 3)
- Node (Id = 4)

  - Node (Id = 5)
  - Node (Id = 6)

    - Node (Id = 7)

Comment: Child is a subtype of Node?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy no, Node and Child is of the same type. I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: [Searching a tree using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062882/searching-a-tree-using-linq) should give you an idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following extension method for flattening hierarchy (see alternative flattening algorithm in answer update below):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;

        var children = childrenSelector(item);
        if (children == null)
            continue;

        foreach (var child in children.Flatten(childrenSelector))
            yield return child;                
    }
}
```

I takes child selector and recursively yields children. Then projection is simple:

```
var result = nodes.Flatten(n => n.Children).Select(n => n.Id);
```

Assume you have following Node class:

```
public class Node
{    
    public Node(int id, params Node[] children)
    {
        Id = id;
        if (children.Any())
            Children = new List<Node>(children);
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then with your sample hierarchy:

```
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node> {
    new Node(1),
    new Node(2, new Node(3)),
    new Node(4, new Node(5),
                new Node(6, new Node(7)))
};
```

Output will be:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

**UPDATE**: You can flatten hierarchy without usage of recursion (for better performance):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
        queue.Enqueue(item);

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        T item = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return item;
        var children = childrenSelector(item);
        if (children == null)
            continue;

        foreach (var child in children)
           queue.Enqueue(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your non-recursive version does a breadth first traversal, which may or may not matter but which should probably be noted. (It will result in 1,2,4,3,5,6,7)

Comment: @SteveRuble Changing it to depth first is as trivial as changing the `Queue` to a `Stack`.  Changing it to a best-first traversal is as trivial as changing it to a Priority Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

```
Func<IEnumerable<Node>, IEnumerable<int>> flatten = null;
flatten = ns =>
{
    return ns.Select(n => n.Id)
        .Concat(ns.SelectMany(n => flatten(n.Children)));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the hierarchy with an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> Flatten(this IEnumerable<Node> source)
{
  if(source == null) 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

  return FlattenIterator(source);
}

private static IEnumerable<Node> FlattenIterator(IEnumerable<Node> source)
{
  foreach(var node in source)
  {
    yield return node;
    foreach(var child in node.Children.Flatten())
    {
      yield return child;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can select the IDs like this:

```
var ids = source.Flatten().Select(n => n.Id);
```