# How can I efficiently query against a tree structure stored in a database using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

I have a table of elements that can be associated to each other (within the same table).

So for example a structure like:

```
[Id]                      Int 
[ParentWithinThisTableId] Int
[AFieldToQueryAgainst]    NVarCharMax
```

At the beginning of the search, I will be given a string query and a single Id (call it `StartId` that points to an element in this table.  What I want to do is compare the string query to the `[AFieldToQueryAgainst]` on the element at the Id given, but also query against the same column for all rows that have `[ParentWithinThisTableId] == StartId` and then all of the rows that have *these* ids as `[ParentWithinThisTableId]`.

The only way I can think to do it is recursively like:

```
    var forms = db.Forms.Where(m => m.ParentWithinThisTableId == this.Id);

    var searchMatches = new List<Form>();

    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        forms = forms.Concat(AddSearches(query, form.Id));
    }

    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        if (form.AFieldToQueryAgainst.Contains(query))
        {
            searchMatches.Add(form);
        }
    }
```

With `AddSearches` being recursive like:

```
    private IQueryable<Form> AddSearches(string query, int startId)
    {
        var items = RepositoryProxy.Context.Forms.Where(m => m.ParentWithinThisTableId == startId);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            items = items.Concat(AddSearches(query, item.Id));
        }

        return items;
    }
```

But this takes about 1.8 seconds run time in my testing on a relatively shallow tree.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  Possibly avoid iterating each of the `IQueryables` until they're all compiled somehow?

Comment: `efficiently` + `tree structure` + `SQL database`.  Pick any two.  You can't have all three (other than using some database extensions as I hear Oracle has).

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this:
[searching-a-tree-using-linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062882/searching-a-tree-using-linq)

Comment: Do you only need to down two levels? Or do you need to recurse until there are no more matches?

Comment: I need to recurse until no more matches, I always struggle to describe these things :)

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just use a self join ?

```
var these = (from p in items
                join x in items on p.Id equals x.ParentId
                where x != null
                select x).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe this gets all rows where *any* `ParentId` is populated right?  Is there a way to limit this to only a certain Id and its descendants?

Comment: you can always add a where clause before the join clause to filter out which items (p) are within your requested range :)