# Selecting the Parents of item from Child ID LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Type Class:

```
public partial class URS_Types
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to make a submethod that will receive the ID of "type" of request, it will then get it's parent (using the parentID), then that will get it's parents, until there isn't other category.

I have tried the below, but obviously this only returns the first type due to the select command, however not sure how to tell it to select all the types.

```
var types = GetURS_Types();

var test = from type in types
           where type.ID == id
           join type2 in types
           on type.ParentID equals type2.ID
           join type3 in types
           on type2.ParentID equals type3.ID
           select type.TypeName;
```

Comment: Is Parent the same class?

Comment: @HunterTran Yes

Comment: Can you modify the `URS_Types` class, or make it a tree structure?

Comment: This might help you work through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/7062882/125981

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a have a list of object URS_Types, with the object having ParentID = 0 being the true parent element.

```
URS_Types parentParent = new URS_Types();
parentParent.ID = 1;
parentParent.ParentID = 0;
parentParent.TypeName= "parentParent";

URS_Types parent = new URS_Types();
parent.ID = 2;
parent.ParentID = 1;
parent.TypeName = "parent";

URS_Types child = new URS_Types();
child.ID = 3;
child.ParentID = 2;
child.TypeName = "child";

URS_Types noParentType = new URS_Types();
noParentType.ID = 4;
noParentType.ParentID = 0;
noParentType.TypeName = "No parent";

List<URS_Types> listType = new List<URS_Types>();
listType.Add(parentParent);
listType.Add(parent);
listType.Add(child);
listType.Add(noParentType);
listType = listType.OrderBy(a => rng.Next()).ToList();
```

with your function `GetURS_Types()` it return and ID of 3 (meaning it's the child object). We can make a small while loop to retrieve the true parent of this object.

```
var childId = GetURS_Types(child); // will return an int: 3
int trueParent = childId; 
URS_Types theTrueParent;
while (trueParent > 0)
{
    theTrueParent = listType.First(x => x.ID == trueParent);
    trueParent = listType.First(x => x.ID == trueParent).ParentID;
}
```

Note: We will never get the object noParentType (unless we ask `GetURS_Types()` for it's ID), because we work our way up the list following the ParentID property.